# how to instantiate a new pair as a value in a Java11 hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I would like to initialize a hashmap in Java11.

```
  import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple

  HashMap<String, Pair<Integer, Double>> m = new HashMap<String, Pair<Integer, Double>>();
```

How can I create a new Pair as value and put it and its key to the hashmap ?

```
  m.put("example_key", new Pair<Integer, Double>(1, 6.17));
```

The above code does not work, i got error:

```
'Pair' is abstract and cannot be instantiated.
```

How can I do the instantiation ?

Comment: Which `Pair` class are you importing?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not clear what `Pair` class are you importing.

Try looking for available `Pair` successors or a static factory method kind of `Pair.of` or `Pair.from`

Comment: It is "org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple".

Comment: Cool, then just use `Pair.of`. See javadoc: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html#of-L-R-